# Way to clear angularJS $cookieStore in one fell swoop instead of cookie by cookie?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, cookiestore

Currently, using angularJS's $cookieStore, I am clearing cookies upon logout one by one.

```
$cookieStore.remove('gender');
$cookieStore.remove('username');
```

I examined the $cookieStore object in console and found that it looks like this.

```
Object {get: function, put: function, remove: function}
```

Is there some way to clear all cookies in $cookieStore without deleting individual cookies?

Answer (score 2):

You might already even have a solution, but unless it's v1.4.x, where you could do (haven't tried it personally)

```
$cookies.getAll();
```

the only efficient way that I came up was like this:

```
angular.forEach( ["cookieA", "cookieB"], function ( key ) {
        $cookieStore.remove( key );
} );
```

Creating a `Service` for that block would be a best approach. You would still have to know all the cookie names that you have used, but it's better than having redundant remove statement. Saves few lines and time :).